# How do I ensure there are no classloader issues in Google Cloud Dataflow's staging location for 2 different versions of the same JAR

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

While running the Google Cloud Dataflow ['WordCount' example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example), I noticed something unexpected. I noticed 2 versions of the same JAR in the staging location!

I had edited my WordCount POM to use a newer SLF4J logging JAR. (1.7.8)

Obviously the newer JAR had deployed alongside the old one. The old JAR had not been deleted.

Based on my previous experience with other Java projects, I suspect this could lead to classloading issues. But perhaps not.

How does Google Cloud dataflow handle potential classloading? Does it use OSGI? Or perhaps something to do with the hash signatures on the ends of the JAR file names?

Or should I be cleaning out the staging location on each deploy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dataflow identifies the necessary files to stage and appends a hash in [PackagingUtil.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/PackageUtil.java) to prevent collisions, so this should not be an issue.  The staged files are explicitly passed to the job in `filesToStage` in [DataflowPipelineRunner.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineRunner.java), rather than looking at the entire contents of the staging directory.